# Redirect After Login In React Native Router Flux

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I am having an issue with RNRF, `Action.SomeRoute()` does not work in my login component, anytime i try `Action.SomeRoute()` it does nothing but works fine in other components, I want to be able to redirect with Actions.SomeRoute(), after logging into my account, I can't seem to get the problem but here is is my code.

My Login Component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text, Animated, ScrollView, Easing} from 'react-native';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import {Actions} from 'react-native-router-flux';
import FitImage from 'react-native-fit-image';
import styles from '../styles/containers/Login';
import Button from '../presenters/partials/Button';
import Input from '../presenters/partials/Input';
import * as Headers from '../presenters/partials/Headers';
import {ActionCreators} from "../actions/_actions";
const logo = require('../assets/images/logo.png');

class Login extends Component{

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {};
    }

    componentWillMount(){...}

    componentDidMount(){...}

    _textChange(key: string, value: string){
        const newState = {};
        newState[key] = value;
        this.setState(newState);
    }

    componentDidUpdate(){
        if (this.props.auth.isAuthenticated) {
            Actions.Dashboard({type: 'reset'});
        }
    }

    render(){
        return (<View style={styles.wrapper}>
                    <View style={styles.logo_container}>
                        <FitImage style={styles.logo} source={logo} />
                        <Headers.H3 style={styles.name}>{'CRS Waterboard'}</Headers.H3>
                </View>
                <Animated.View 
                    style={[styles.form_container, {
                        flex: this.state.formContainerAnimation
                    }]}>
                    <Animated.View style={[styles.form, {
                        opacity: this.state.formOpacityAnimation,
                        height: this.state.formHeightAnimation
                    }]}>
                        <ScrollView style={styles.formInner}>
                            <Headers.H4 style={styles.welcome}>{'Sign In To Continue'}</Headers.H4>
                            <Input style={styles.input} 
                                    onChangeText={this._textChange.bind(this, 'username')}
                                    placeholder={'Username'} 
                                    radius={'large'}/>
                            <Input style={styles.input} 
                                    onChangeText={this._textChange.bind(this, 'password')}
                                    placeholder={'Password'} 
                                    radius={'large'}
                                    secureTextEntry={true}/>
                            <Button style={styles.loginButton} onPress={this._login.bind(this)} type={'primary'} size={'large'}> Sign In </Button>
                        </ScrollView>
                    </Animated.View>
                </Animated.View>
            </View>);
    }

    _login(){
        // get username and password from state
        let {username, password} = this.state;
        // if username and password were entered
        if (username.length > 0 && password.length > 0) {
            // get creds from form
            let creds = {username, password};
        }
        // log user in
        this.props.login(creds);
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    // map actions to dispatch and return
    return bindActionCreators(ActionCreators, dispatch);
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    let {auth, route} = state;
    return {auth, route};
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Login);
```

My Routes:

```
   <ConnectedRouter>
        <Scene key={"root"}>
            <Scene
              key="tabbar"
              tabs={true}
              tabBarStyle={styles.tabBarStyle}>

              <Scene icon={TabIcon} key={'dashboardTab'} title={'Dashboard'}>
                <Scene
                    key={'Dashboard'}
                    direction={'horizontal'}
                    component={Dashboard} 
                    title={'Dashboard'} 
                    hideNavBar={true}
                    initial={(this.props.initial == 'Home' ? true : false )}
                    sceneStyle={[styles.sceneStyleWithTabar]}/>
              </Scene>

                <Scene
                    icon={TabIcon}
                    key={'History'}
                    direction={'horizontal'}
                    component={Home} 
                    title={'History'}
                    sceneStyle={[styles.sceneStyleWithNavbar, styles.sceneStyleWithTabar]}
                    navigationBarStyle={styles.navbar}
                    titleStyle={styles.title}
                    titleWrapperStyle={styles.titleWrapper}
                    renderLeftButton={(nav) => {return null;}}/>
                <Scene key="newTab" title="New" icon={TabIcon}>
                    <Scene
                        key={'New'}
                        direction={'horizontal'}
                        component={New} 
                        title={'New Reading'} 
                        sceneStyle={[styles.sceneStyleWithNavbar, styles.sceneStyleWithTabar]}
                        navigationBarStyle={styles.navbar}
                        titleStyle={styles.title}
                        titleWrapperStyle={styles.titleWrapper}
                        renderLeftButton={(nav) => {return null;}}/>
                    <Scene
                        key={'NewReading'}
                        direction={'horizontal'}
                        component={NewReading} 
                        title={'New Reading'} 
                        sceneStyle={[styles.sceneStyleWithNavbar, styles.sceneStyleWithTabar]}
                        navigationBarStyle={styles.navbar}
                        titleStyle={styles.title}
                        titleWrapperStyle={styles.titleWrapper}
                        renderLeftButton={(nav) => {return null;}}/>
                    <Scene
                        key={'ReadingComplete'}
                        direction={'horizontal'}
                        component={ReadingComplete} 
                        title={'Invoice'} 
                        sceneStyle={[styles.sceneStyleWithNavbar, styles.sceneStyleWithTabar]}
                        navigationBarStyle={styles.navbar}
                        titleStyle={styles.title}
                        titleWrapperStyle={styles.titleWrapper}
                        renderLeftButton={(nav) => {return null;}}/>
                    <Scene key={'modal'}>
                        <Scene key={'root'}>
                            <Scene
                                key={'PrintInvoice'}
                                component={PrintInvoice} />
                        </Scene>
                    </Scene>
                </Scene>
                <Scene
                    icon={TabIcon}
                    key={'Account'}
                    direction={'horizontal'}
                    component={Account} 
                    title={'My Account'} 
                    sceneStyle={[styles.sceneStyleWithNavbar, styles.sceneStyleWithTabar]}
                    navigationBarStyle={styles.navbar}
                    titleStyle={styles.title}
                    titleWrapperStyle={styles.titleWrapper}
                    renderLeftButton={(nav) => {return null;}}/>
            </Scene>
            <Scene 
                key={'Login'}
                tabs={false}
                direction={'horizontal'}
                component={Login} 
                title={'Login'}
                hideNavBar={true}
                initial={(this.props.initial == 'Login' ? true : false )} />
        </Scene>
    </ConnectedRouter>
```

Will really appreciate your help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to check authenticate status in componentWillReceiveProps

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
 if (this.nextProps.auth.isAuthenticated) {
   Actions.Dashboard({type: 'reset'});
 }
}
```

Comment: I already implemented that, but with component did update, and it sees the new update but what I got wrong was this, RNRF doesn't allow you just move to a new route inside a group of routes in this case the tab group, there's a solution which requires cloning, but every time I do that my UI breaks so as a solution I route to the group using its key in this case i will do `Actions.tabbar({type: 'reset'})` this will load the first scene in the group for me, which is fine for now! Will prep and post an answer thanks!

Comment: Any updates on this @DanielBarde? I'm running into what appears to be literally the exact same issue.